# Change Link Wrapping Unique Identifier after email has been rendered

Tags: marketing-cloud, ssjs, redirect, custom-link, tracking

To conform with a new law, we now must provide customers the option to view received emails in multiple languages at ease. We have solved this by dynamically generating the content for other languages via the view-in-browser messagecontext. Our problem is that for modules where 1 variable is associated with a link in multiple languages, the link gets wrapped with 1 single identifier for link tracking. So in the VIB, you click the link and it goes to the webpage with the original language query param. See module example below:

```
<center>
<a style="color: #989291; text-decoration: underline; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 11px; font-weight: bold; color: #989291;" href="%%=RedirectTo(@toggle_eng)=%%">English Email</a> | 
<a style="color: #989291; text-decoration: underline; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 11px; font-weight: bold; color: #989291;" href="%%=RedirectTo(@toggle_fre)=%%">French Email</a>
</center>
<br>
<br>

%%[
SET @link = ''
/* Pre-define all possible links and set to specific variable */
SET @FR_link = "https://www.example.ca/fr"
SET @EN_link = "https://www.example.ca/en"

/* Set EN and FR links to respective variables already declared */
IF @language == 'FR' THEN
  SET @link = @FR_link
  SET @test = "Test, but French"
ELSE
  SET @link = @EN_link
  SET @test = "Test"
ENDIF
]%%

<span style="color:black; font-size:24px">
  <a href="%%=RedirectTo(@link)=%%" target="_blank" alias="link_testing" style="text-decoration:none;">%%=v(@test)=%%</a>
</span>
```

When sending to the inbox initially, you get the wrapped link identifier of https://click.enews.xxxxxx.com/?qs=af91537af1610b0f467eb6ddde931f777c3e82839840981f1a4be61afc996aa5abaa84c44d05d72927f09776253387da7c311864e4c208b7 and when you toggle to the other language, that identifier stays the same. Any thoughts on how to force the link wrapping cache to reset or anything similar?

Answer (score 0):

You would need to prevent the tracking parameters adding to your URL. I can see 2 ways:

1. You can uncheck the "Track clicks" box when you are going to send the email
2. If you still want keep the current setting and track the other URLs, you can use the CONCAT function AMPscript to prevent the parameters from being added to a single link:

I modified a bit your code above, it supposes to keep the initial URL without adding the parameters:

```
%%[
SET @language = 'vn' /* TEST */
SET @link = ''
/* Pre-define all possible links and set to specific variable */
SET @FR_link = "https://www.example.ca/fr"
SET @EN_link = "https://www.example.ca/en"

/* Set EN and FR links to respective variables already declared */
IF @language == 'FR' THEN
  SET @test = "Test, but French"
  SET @link = Concat('<a href="',@FR_link,'" target="_blank" alias="link_testing" style="text-decoration:none;">',@test,'</a>') 
ELSE
  SET @test = "Test"
  SET @link = Concat('<a href="',@EN_link,'" target="_blank" alias="link_testing" style="text-decoration:none;">',@test,'</a>') 
ENDIF
]%%

<span style="color:black; font-size:24px">
%%=v(@link)=%% 
</span>
```

Read more about this way [HERE](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000383129&type=1)